# Is there an AddRange equivalent for a HashSet in C#

Tags: c#, collections, hashset, addrange

With a list you can do:

```
list.AddRange(otherCollection);
```

There is no add range method in a `HashSet`.
What is the best way to add another `ICollection` to a `HashSet`?

Answer (score 835, accepted):

For `HashSet<T>`, the name is [`UnionWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx).

This is to indicate the distinct way the `HashSet` works. You cannot safely `Add` a set of random elements to it like in `Collections`, some elements may naturally evaporate.

I think that `UnionWith` takes its name after "merging with another `HashSet`", however, there's an overload for `IEnumerable<T>` too.

Comment: Imho, `HashSet` (and `ISet`) was created with mathematically set term. `UnionWith` was the nearer term. Except for `Except`, which clearly should be named as `Subtract`, mathematically speaking.

Answer (score 10):

This is one way:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool AddRange<T>(this HashSet<T> source, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        bool allAdded = true;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            allAdded &= source.Add(item);
        }
        return allAdded;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could have performance issues, as the hash set will be reordered on each iteration.

Comment: What is the alternative? UnionWith does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0) with LINQ. This will append a collection or specifically a `HashSet<T>` onto another.

```
    var A = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };  // contents of HashSet 'A'
    var B = new HashSet<int>() { 4, 5 };     // contents of HashSet 'B'

    // Concat 'B' to 'A'
    A = A.Concat(B).ToHashSet();    // Or one could use: ToList(), ToArray(), ...

    // 'A' now also includes contents of 'B'
    Console.WriteLine(A);
    >>>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

**NOTE:** `Concat()` creates an entirely new collection. Also, `UnionWith()` is faster than Concat().

"*... this (`Concat()`) also assumes you actually have access to the variable referencing the hash set and are allowed to modify it, which is not always the case.*" – @PeterDuniho

Comment: It's true, you _could_ use `Concat()`. But doing so is 100% worse than just calling the `UnionWith()` method that was designed for the purpose, as the accepted answer proposes. Note that this also assumes you actually have access to the variable referencing the hash set and are allowed to modify it, which is not always the case.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I assume Concat() is easier utilized than RoadieRich solution of adding each element individually using Add(). Moreover, to use his solution, one would have to copy and paste his block of code to even utilize his solution. My solution, while it is not the best, is significantly slimmer than RoadieRich solution. However, your reasoning is very understandable.

Comment: _"I assume Concat() would be faster than the second answer by RoadieRich of adding each element individually using Add()"_ -- why would you assume that? Your example creates **three** new objects (two iterators and a new `HashSet<T>`), and has to populate that third object from scratch, while calling `Add()` iteratively creates no new objects, and only has to add the elements that are actually new. I doubt your proposal is more performant than the built-in `UnionWith()` method _or_ the extension method proposed in the other answer.

Comment: _"one would have to copy and paste his block of code"_ -- and they don't have to do so to use yours? Not that copy/paste is in any way a material concern anyway, but it's not like your code magically gets transported to someone else's project. It either has to be copied and pasted or retyped as well.

Comment: And again, your example _requires_ that it be possible to actually _replace_ the existing collection with a new one, something that is not actually always true, and in any case is a significant departure from the original requirement that the solution be **equivalent** to `AddRange()`. The question specifically ask to _"add another `ICollection` to a `HashSet`"_, and yet your proposed solution does not do that at all; instead, it creates a whole new `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: _"... and they don't have to do so to use yours?"_ @PeterDuniho RoadieRich solution is 9 lines long, compared to my 1 line `A = A.Concat(B).ToHashSet()` using a LINQ function. My solution is pretty clean cut. How is 1 line the same as 9 lines using RoadieRich solution. I do understand you reasoning `UnionWith()` is a better suited solution.

Comment: @PeterDuniho would you recommend my answer to be removed?