# Adding list of strings from one list to another list

Tags: c#

I have one outer List BigList and then in my switch statements I have a bunch of other List smallerList variables.
When I get to each of these cases in my switch I want to add those to the BigList
But I also don't want to add repeated ones.
How do we do that?

```
private List<string> MyMethod()
{
  List<string> BigList = null;
  for each( string name in MyListOfStringsThatComesIn)
  {
     tName = name;
     switch(tName)
     {
         case "dsdds":
            // List<string> smallerList;
            // add it to BigList
         case "fdfdf":
            // List<string> smallerList2;
            // add it to BigList
         case "vbbughb":
            // List<string> smallerList3;
            // add it to BigList
```

Comment: Make BigList a HashSet, that way it won't have duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If duplicates aren't allowed i would use a `HashSet<string>` in the first place:

```
HashSet<string> bigSet = new HashSet<string>();
// add strings ...
```

If you want to add the whole `List<string>` into the set you can either use `bigSet.Add` in a loop or [`HashSet.UnionWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
case "dsdds":
   bigSet.UnionWith(smallerList);
```

If you need to return a list you can use

```
return new List<string>(bigSet);
```

Comment: Looks like HashSet doesn't have a AddRange method, so How am I supposed to add the small list to the biglist?

Comment: I believe that OP is trying to add smaller lists to `BigList` (or `bigSet`). You can use `UnionWith` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267034/is-there-an-addrange-equivalent-for-a-hashset-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DevWannaBe, you might be interested in ^

Comment: @DevWannaBe: i have edited my answer, you can use a  loop or `bigSet.UnionWith(smallerList);`

Answer (score 1):

To create a new list based on the unique values of another one :

```
List<string> BigList = MyListOfStringsThatComesIn.Distinct().ToList();
```

To add new unique values from another list :

```
//assume the BigList contains something already...
BigList.AddRange(BigList.Except(MyListOfStringsThatComesIn));
```

Comment: But that's not _adding_, it's _replacing_ the list of strings.

Comment: Base on the example that might be good enough since the list is just created prior to the adding.

Comment: @DonBoitnott the big list is initially empty in the current context. Adding or Creating make no difference this is case.

Comment: While that is true, I would avoid making assumptions, especially against already bad pseudo-code.  Should make for more complete and useful answers.

Comment: @DonBoitnott repeated `!Contains` and `Add` will be rather inefficient in this case. And not to mentions, it would break the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's probably a more efficient way to do what you want, but based on what you have shown, you can either:

Look for strings that don;t exist in the parent list:

```
BigList.AddRange(smallerList.Except(BigList));
```

or just add them all (allowing duplicates) and call `Distinct` at the end:

```
BigList.AddRange(smallerList);
...
///add other lists


BigList = BigList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Also, you should probably intialize your list to an empty list rather then `null`:

```
List<string> BigList = new List<string>();
```

Comment: I was thinking about calling Distinct at the end too :) Wasn't sure if it will actually work!